# Selenium match attribute from outerHTML using Python3

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to match the attribute "translate=subscriptions" from the following outerHTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-info ng-scope" translate="subscriptions" href="javascript:;" ng-class="{selected:tab=='subscriptions'}" ng-click="selectTab('subscriptions')">Subscriptions</a>
```

Note that i have multiple tabs that are using the same class name (btn btn-info ng-scope)

See below my tries:

`WebDriverWait(driver,default_wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.btn.btn-info.ng-scope[@translate='Subscriptions']"))).click()` `WebDriverWait(driver,default_wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.ng-click[selectTab='subscriptions']"))).click()`          `WebDriverWait(driver,default_wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[translate='subscriptions']"))).click()`  `WebDriverWait(driver,default_wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.translate,"subscriptions"))).click()`
`WebDriverWait(driver,default_wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.translate.subscriptions"))).click()`    `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector "#translate" ).click()`    `WebDriverWait(driver,default_wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,".//*[@translate='subscriptions']"))).click()`
`WebDriverWait(driver,default_wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[text()='Subscriptions']"))).click() // in site the Subscription tab is diplayed with "S" uppercase`    `WebDriverWait(driver,default_wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'Subscriptions')]"))).click() // in site the Subscription tab is diplayed with "S" uppercase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently i used a wrong function, it worked with the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@translate='subscriptions']").click()
```